# "No such file or directory error" When using jasper with openerp

Tags: jasper-reports, odoo

We have developed reports using jasper and all was ok when we developed it.

On my laptop I am able to print the report just fine this is where I ran the server and tested it.

However when I uploaded it to my ubuntu server and users try to access the same report we get an error.

```
"2
No such file or directory

(<type 'exceptions.OSError'>, OSError(2, 'No such file or directory'), <traceback object
at 0x7f63b8485ab8>) "
```

Its been two days and we are stuck. Please advice what must be wrong.

I am not sure what is wrong here.

Thank you
Vishal

Comment: check for /  vs \ , as this is the most common mistake

Comment: no its not that as the code handles the path actually. I am using some community module for it

Comment: Post some code. How are you loading the reports? Are you using the JasperReports API? Are you using JasperServer? Are you running iReport as a desktop app? How are is the code integrated with OpenERP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I solved it was by installing open jdk. As jasper is a java file it needs the compiler and the server did not have this.